# Apt broken after mid install close

Tags: apt, package-management

My apt is will not let me interact with a single package, `account-plugin-google`.  Here is the output when I try `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
dylan@dylanredfield:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-google
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-google
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,372 B of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'account-plugin-ubuntuone' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'account-plugin-tools' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'account-plugin-flickr' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 283341 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../account-plugin-google_0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking account-plugin-google (0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/accounts.google.com.conf', which is also in package kaccounts-providers 4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dylan@dylanredfield:~$
```

I have been scrounging google for the last today doings a lot to try to fix the issue, but nothing has worked. Should I just call it quits and reinstall?

Comment: Known bug apparently: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kaccounts-providers/+bug/1622499

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that the `account-plugin-google_0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb` package (aka `account-plugin-google`) is trying to overwrite a file (`/etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/accounts.google.com.conf`) that was installed by a previously installed package, `kaccounts-providers 4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1` (aka `kaccounts-providers`).

The quick and dirty fix is to

```
sudo mv /etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/accounts.google.com.conf \
        /etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/accounts.google.com.conf.original
```

Retry the installation, then compare the two files and decide to use one, or the other, or a combination.

Or, you could uninstall the `kaccounts-providers` package, **BUT This May Have Side Effects**. Side effects could include being asked to uninstall other crucial packages, destroying your access to what `kaccounts-proveders` provides, and nightmares you haven't even considered yet.